# Composition of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I have question as follows:

Let $V$  be a vector space of dimension  3 over $\Bbb R $  and let t $\in$ $\mathcal L (V,V)$ have eigenvalue $-2,1,2$ . Use the Calyey-Hamilton theorem to find $t^4$

I know that $(t-2)(t-1)(t+2) =0$ so

$t^3 = t^2 +4t -4id$

I am unsure how to proceed

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t^3=\color{green}{t^2+4t-4Id.}\implies t^4=t^3+4t^2-4t=(\color{green}{t^2+4t-4Id.})+4t^2-4t=\;\ldots$$

Comment: @Matthew, multiply the first equation by $\;t\;$ ... :) This is, imo, the easiest way.

Comment: I was be stupid :(

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Write the long division of $x^4$ by the characteristic polynomial.

**Details**

We find
$$x^4=(x+1)\chi_t(x)+5x^2-4$$
so by the Cayely-Hamilton theorem we have
$$t^4=5t^2-4\operatorname{Id}$$